# Prime k tuples with Sage

Tags: primes, sage

As an example, suppose I search for prime numbers in the arithmetic progression $30n+11$ ( with $$ simulated LaTeX math mode), To print these prime numbers in Sage, I use the following

```
sage : [30*n+11 for n in range(30) if (30*n+11).is_prime()]
```

This print `[11,41,71,101,131,191,251,281,311,401,431,461,491,521,641,701,761,821,881]`

The modification I am looking to make is to print the prime numbers $p$ such that $p+0,p+2,p+6,p+8$ are also prime, in this case print only `[11,101,191,821]`, (see [oeis A007530](https://oeis.org/A007530)).

I must say that the `primes` package in `R` its fine, but with large numbers it crashes (at least in r studio cloud). That is why I go to Sage, to see if supports 7 or 8 digit numbers (for example $100000*n+1234567$). Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Sage certainly supports 7 or 8 digit numbers, and more. For example, the following works: `(10^100 + 267).is_prime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple modification of the original code works:

```
[30*n+11 for n in range(30) if (30*n+11).is_prime() and (30*n+11+2).is_prime() and (30*n+11+6).is_prime() and
(30*n+11+8).is_prime()]
```

A slight variation:

```
sage: L = (30*n + 11 for n in range(30))
sage: [a for a in L if a.is_prime() and (a+2).is_prime() and (a+6).is_prime() and (a+8).is_prime()]
[11, 101, 191, 821]
```